# Angular 4 - View settings

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to build an angular app which has a normal registration/login form and some different alt page.

My problem is that I haven't got any idea how to control different views. For example if you log in with normal user type you can see view 1.

If you log in with other user type you see different view than the other.

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: It is a page where you should start: https://angular.io/guide/router. Keyword: "routing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to the specific view in a Guard like this:

Use `CanActivateChild` for protecting `children: []` components in your routing file, otherwise use the interface `CanActivate`. The applied logic stays the same.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, CanActivateChild} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../services';

@Injectable()
export class LoginAuthGuard implements CanActivateChild {

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  canActivateChild(): boolean {
    if (this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
      if (**normal user type **) {
         this.router.navigate(['/view1']);
      } else {
         this.router.navigate(['/view2']);
      }

      return true;
    } else {

      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```